# \part Not Appearing in Table of Contents (Memoir)

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, parts

In the `memoir` class, I want to include `\part` in my book. I have used the code from p.78 of the Memoir manual, tweaked slightly, to change the look of the `\part` title. However, something is causing the `\part` information to not be included in the Table of Contents. The code between the `%` seems to be the problem. So, how do I get the formatting I want in the text for part titles, and still get the parts included in the table of contents?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%

\renewcommand{\part}[1]{%
    \cleardoublepage % start a new recto page
    \beforepartskip % space before Name and Number
    \midpartskip % space after Name and Number
    \renewcommand*{\parttitlefont}{\centering\HUGE\normalfont}
    \printparttitle{#1} % print the title
    \partpageend
} % finish off

%%%%%%%%%%%  

\renewcommand{\partpageend}{%
    \afterpartskip
    \normalsize
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Test Part 1}
\chapter{Name}
\lipsum*[1] 

\part{Test Part 2}

\lipsum*[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are the parts numbered in the TOC? The default is Roman numerals (e.g., **I**, **II**, **III**, ...). The way your part pages are set up now should only print (e.g.) 'Test Part 1' but also print a plain page number at the bottom of the page.

Comment: The parts are not numbered in the text and there are no page numbers on the page or the next page (which is what I want). I have not included in the MWE the rest of the sty file as it has not impact on the problem. Ideally, in the TOC, each part would be a centered title, normal font, with the part title preceded by PART X: as in PART I: Test Part 1.

Comment: @kgrady: Your definition of `\part` can't work as expected, since most of its desired features have been omitted by your `\renewcommand{\part}` especially the fact that `\part` is a command with moving arguments and actually using either `\@part` or `\@spart` -- this is never called by your renewed macro. The mentioned page (on p.80 of the current manual) is a bit misleading, I think

Comment: Seems like I shouldn't use `\addcontentsline` since that would mean I have to update the sty file every time I change the `\part` text in the main file.

Comment: So what code should I use to update the formatting as I have done, and still retain the other features of `\part`, including insertion into the TOC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to remove the “Part I” from the part page and the numbering from the table of contents.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand*{\parttitlefont}{\centering\HUGE\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\mempreaddparttotochook}{%
  \global\chardef\keepsecnumdepth=\value{secnumdepth}%
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1000}%
}
\renewcommand{\mempostaddparttotochook}{%
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{\keepsecnumdepth}%
}
\renewcommand{\printpartname}{}
\renewcommand{\partnamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printpartnum}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%  

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\part{Test Part 1}
\chapter{Name}
\lipsum*[1] 

\part{Test Part 2}

\lipsum*[1]

\end{document}
```

Before the code that does the TOC related jobs I set `secnumdepth` to a very large negative value; this suppresses the numbering, but still adds the part to the table of contents. After that, the counter is reset to its previous value.

Next, I redefine the macros responsible for printing “Part I” to do nothing.

Unrelated, but I also added `*` next to `\tableofcontents`: I can't stand the “Contents” line just below the title “Contents”.

Comment: Very nice! Simple and yes, solved the text preceding the part issue. I had the * in my full document, just missed it in the MWE. I still go with the manual leaving a lot to be desired.